# Make something similar to Shiny Leaflet example without using R

Tags: shiny, leaflet

Is it possible to make something similar to [this](http://shiny.rstudio.com/gallery/superzip-example.html) example, which is built with the Shiny Leaflet library, but without actually using R? 
Are there any leaflet control plugins for scaling points based on a value or for making charts like in the example?
I tried to find out what the shiny library uses for making charts, but I didn't - maybe due to my lack of experience with R..

Thanks for any help in advance!

Comment: You can always use `Javascript` to fiddle with controls and reactives and other models as `leaflet` is an open source `JS` library [look here for more info](http://leafletjs.com/)

Comment: @PorkChop Thanks for the reply! I know I can use Javascript to add custom controls. It just seems like that would be a lot of work and maybe it's possible to reuse something from the shiny library. Or maybe someone already did something like this (I didn't find anything in the plugins on the leaflet page, but who knows?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Shiny charts are being generated as static .png images on the server side and updated as things are changed. So there's not much you can reuse there. However, you can style circleMarkers in Leaflet in ways that are similar to that example map. Scaling the color and size based on a value can be done with styling functions called when you create the layer.

If you have some point geometry in a GeoJSON object called dots, you could do:

```
dotlayer = L.geoJson(dots, {
    pointToLayer: function (feature, latlng) {
        return L.circleMarker(latlng, style(feature));
    },
    onEachFeature: onEachDot
}).addTo(map);
```

where style(feature) is a function:

```
function style(feature) {
    return {
        radius: getRadius(feature.properties.size),
        fillColor: getColor(feature.properties.year),
        color: "#000",
        weight: 1,
        opacity: 0,
        fillOpacity: 0.8
    };
}
```

which in turn calls two other functions to get the color and radius from the feature properties:

```
function getColor(y) {
    return y > 2000 ? '#6068F0' : 
           y > 1980 ? '#7660C9' : 
           y > 1960 ? '#8C58A3' : 
           y > 1940 ? '#A3507C' : 
           y > 1920 ? '#B94856' :
                      '#D04030';
}

function getRadius(y) {
    r = Math.sqrt(y / Math.PI)
    return r;
}
```

The color ramp is calculated using an external utility like [colorbrewer](http://colorbrewer2.org/). In this example function, the radius is scaled so that the area of the circle is proportional to the original quantity, but your function could scale it in whatever way makes the most sense for your map.

Plots and legends do require the use of controls, but it's easier to do when you have an example to work from. So here is a fiddle with some not-very-graceful examples:

http://fiddle.jshell.net/nathansnider/o563bg44/

It doesn't have all bells and whistles of the shiny map (like updating the plot automatically as the map is moved), but it's a start.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the reply! I actually ended up making some custom controls, one of them uses d3 (for the charts). But your exmple definetly has some contents I will add to my application. Really helpful answer :)